# How to pass nullable field to custom function in reporting services (SSRS) report?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Using SSRS 2012 with Visual Studio 2012.

I have a TextBox with expression defined something like this:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(First(Fields!Cost.Value, "SomeTable") Is Nothing, "", Code.GetCostAsString(First(Fields!Cost.Value, "SomeTable")))
```

"Cost" is a nullable decimal type. 
"GetCostAsString" is custom VB.NET like this:

```
Function GetCostAsString(val As Decimal) As String

    Dim res As Decimal = Val * 1.1D
    Return res.ToString("0.##") 

End Function
```

(In reality, the custom code will be more complicated than this, which is why I want to use a custom function).

Question: Is it possible to move more code into the function, so that the function can also handle the case where the field value is null (i.e. "Nothing" in VB.NET) ?.

e.g. so the expression becomes:

```
=Code.GetCostAsString(First(Fields!Cost.Value, "SomeTable"))
```

And the function is:

```
Function GetCostAsString(val As ????) As String

    ' return empty string if val is Nothing, else do other stuff with decimal value. 

End Function
```

What type can I put at "????" so that it can accept a nothing value ?

Comment: Have you tried to define the param in the function as `Nullable (Of Decimal)`?

Comment: Great, I posted that as the answer for others to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Nullable(Of Decimal)`, like this:

```
Function GetCostAsString(val As Nullable(Of Decimal)) As String
    ' return empty string if val is Nothing, else do other stuff with decimal value. 
    If val.HasValue Then
        ' Do stuff here and return decimal value
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Note: The `HasValue` property is the equivalent of checking if the `Decimal` is `Nothing` or not; `False` means it is `Nothing`, thus the `Else` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a nullable type as the parameter type in VB.NET code, in this case `Nullable (Of Decimal)`, to match your SQL data type.